# Find the Taylor series about $x = 1$ for $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{(x − 2)^2}$ .

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

Find the Taylor series about $x = 1$ for $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{(x − 2)^2}$ . Express your answer in sigma notation, simplified as much as possible.

This is a practice question that I am having trouble with. I know how to get it about $x=0$, but it is the x=1 part that confuses me.

Comment: How about consider $g(x)=f(x-1)$?

Answer (score 2):

One trick you can use is to notice that the function is almost the derivative of $-\frac{1}{x-2}$ then you can use this together with the geometric series: $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k = \frac{1}{1-x}$$ and that you can integrate / differentiate power series term-wise inside their radius of convergence.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do are compute the derivatives of f at $x=1$.  These (each divided by the appropriate factorial) will be the coefficients of your Taylor series.  The monomial terms of the series will be of the form $(x-1)^r$, for $r$ in the set of nonnegative integers.

Answer (score 0):

Just find the nth derivative of `1/(x-2)^2` and insert it in its formula by substituting appropriate values for different variables. Here is a reference. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TaylorSeries.html

Just replace a with 1 and find nth derivative about x= 1.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. It is encouraged to try and typeset the math one writes. I tried helping you with that here. It is basically LaTeX code which math can be typeset in and is easy to find tutorials and sources online to get started ( if you don't already know it ).

Answer (score 0):

$f(x) 
= \dfrac{1}{(x − 2)^2}
$

Let $y = x-1$,
or $x= y+1$.
We want to find the expansion
about $y = 0$.

$\begin{array}\\
g(y)
&=f(y+1)\\
&= \dfrac{1}{(y-1)^2}\\
&= \dfrac{1}{(1-y)^2}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1)y^n\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1)(x-1)^n\\
&\text{and we could stop here, but, for the fun of it,...}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1)\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}x^k(-1)^{n-k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{n=k}^{\infty} (n+1) \binom{n}{k}x^k(-1)^{n-k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x^k(-1)^k\sum_{n=k}^{\infty} (n+1) \binom{n}{k}(-1)^{n}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x^k(-1)^k\sum_{n=k}^{\infty} \frac{(n+1)!}{k!(n-k)!}(-1)^{n}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(k+1)x^k(-1)^k\sum_{n=k}^{\infty} \frac{(n+1)!}{(k+1)!(n-k)!}(-1)^{n}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(k+1)x^k(-1)^k\sum_{n=k}^{\infty} \binom{n+1}{k+1}(-1)^{n}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(k+1)x^k(-1)^k\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{n+k+1}{k+1}(-1)^{n}\\
&\text{and this is clearly divergent, so please disregard the last 7 lines}\\
\end{array}
$